# Angular 6 ChartJS create canvas dynamically and create graph on it - an example?

Tags: angular, dynamic, graph, chart.js, element

Does anybody have an example of how to create dynamically canvas under *ngFor and use those canvas to create a CharJs on them?

for example:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of Products; let i = index">
  <canvas id="canvas{{i}}" #myId></canvas>
</div>
```

What do I have to use to get myId: @ViewChild? @ViewChildren?
How to get the elements reference to use in

```
var chart = new Chart( =>'element'<=, {....});
```

Could be one or more canvas and graphs depending on how many products in array Products.

Please, if is possible show an example.

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/Ninja-Squad/globe42/tree/master/frontend/src/app/chart

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an example. Still looking for one myself, and while I'm not sure how useful this comment is considering I'm late 24 days...

Off the top of my head you could use a component to display each chart. Each component will be responsible for rendering their chart. And then in the ngFor loop, you'd declare the component, rather than the chart.

Comment: is there any solution for that?

Comment: I do not know what you mean. My answer is a solution to the problem. Build smart components which will handle the chart creation on their own. Use ngOnDestroy when done with the chart, just in case.